# Copy multiple files of one type into another directory in shell

Tags: shell

I'm trying to copy all files of ".sh" saved in one directory to another.

I can copy the entire directory using

```
cp -rp ~/Documents/ToCopy ~/Documents/CopyToHere
```

but I cannot figure out how to select only the .sh files

Is there also anyway to change the file names of the copied files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cp -rp ~/Documents/ToCopy/*.sh ~/Documents/CopyToHere
```

The `*` is a wildcard character that represents any number of characters in the filenames, so `*.sh` matches any file in that directory that ends in *sh*.

I'm pretty sure the wildcard character (`*`) is parsed by the shell itself, not by the `cp` command (so watch out if you are calling it from somewhere that isn't a shell).

Comment: That works great, thanks.  Would there be away to change the name of the individual files with this method? Or at least add a string of text to the end of the file name?

Comment: @Jon - For that you'd want to loop the files into a `mv` command. e.g. `for a in *.sh; do; mv "$a" "${a}.appended-text"; done;` - search for info on bash parameter expansion, for more goodies, find/replace and more.

Comment: @Jon: You can use a similar loop technique with the `cp` command if you want to keep the original files and make the copies have different names.

Answer (score 0):

You can try typing

```
cp -rp ~/Documents/*.sh ~/Documents/CopyToHere
```

The *.sh selects all files in the directory whose names end in ".sh" using regular expressions.  As another example, you could copy all files whose names contain the word "pizza" by typing `*pizza*` on the command line.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing `*.sh` so that you have `cp ~/Documents/*.sh ~/Documents/CopyToHere` ?  That should work...

Comment: Whoops. I thought I put an asterisk in there.  It should have been *.sh like everyone else said.  Unless the asterisk got removed by the formatting, which I am not yet familiar with...